# Is it possible to hit without bruise?

Tags: technique

I got a very strong hit and it had almost no bruise. How is it possible to hit in this way? Is it a special technique?

Comment: If you have seen it happen for yourself, why are you asking whether it is possible?

Comment: To understand how can it be done? Has the attacker used special technique? Is there a way to faster protect yourself/ heal from such attacks?

Comment: This needs way more information.  what kind of hit, what is the goal of the hit, what situation, is there a style of martial arts in question, etc...  Way vague on this question, please add alot of specificity to get an answer.

Comment: Depending on the focus of the technique the bruising may have been internal and thus not visible.

Comment: Seems clear to me.  What's the problem with this question and answer?

Comment: @HuwEvans Is it asking about how bruising works? Is it asking about how to heal bruising? Is it asking about how to either avoid or create bruising when hitting someone? Is it asking about mythical ki-powered magic that does not create bruising? In its current form, the question is gibberish. In turns, this means that the answer is bad because it does not answer the question -- it cannot do so!

Comment: Looks clear to me. He wants to know about hitting people hard without bruising them. How do you do it?

Comment: @HuwEvans If you have a problem with the closure for this question, open a meta discussion. Comment are not the place to discus this extensively.

Comment: @HuwEvans If it is clear to you how to reword this (or any other closed or on-hold) question to get a good, answerable question that matches the original author's intent, please edit it.

Comment: @mattm Sometimes it is possible to determine what the askers wants even if they phrased it badly. In that case, an edit (with a comment) is generally a good thing we should all do. However, if the question could be asking several different things (like this one) then it is impossible for anyone but the asked to clarify it. *This is all the "on hold" means!* A small amount of clarification could make any of the above interesting questions. Only Avi can make the questions clearer. If they cannot be bothered to do that, the question will eventually be closed.

Comment: The only thing I asked is if there is What is the way (if any) to hit and no bruise will be left on the body of the attacked person.

Comment: @Avi Then please delete your comment containing "Is there a way to faster protect yourself/ heal from such attacks?"

Comment: It is just  a continuity to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (As you have seen demonstrated on yourself).

What causes a bruise is actually blood leaking into tissue from damaged vessels. The colors of the bruise are the blood cells dying and decaying in the tissues and being reabsorbed.

Even if you get really hard, if the angle or surface area of the strike is such that no blood vessels get damaged, then you won't get leakage, and hence no bruise. This tends to happen with flatter strikes that have a large surface area (Such as an instep round kick to the outside thigh), or strikes that hit an area with a relatively low number of blood vessels.

If you get hit with a more concentrated force in a smaller area, then the odds of you getting a bruise from it go up. It is not, however, a guarantee that you will or will not get a bruise.

Additionally, if you do get an internal bruise, the blood may not make its way up enough to be visible. It is still there, just not visible.

Comment: By answering a controversial question, you stopped it being revised into something better and answerable. As such, we are left with a terrible question and a poor answer.

Comment: @Sardathrion - You're right. We all make mistakes.

Comment: I have made my share as well. What is the saying? Ah, yes: wise men learn from other people 's mistakes!